# Framework para graficos

Tags: c#, gráfico, aspx

Bom dia,
Estou com um grafico que foi desenvolvido utilizado o DevExpress(https://demos.devexpress.com/XtraChartsDemos/BarViewTypes/BarSeries.aspx). No gráfico que estou utilizando ele tem cinco colunas e cada mês do ano, 5 colunas em janeiro, 5 em fevereiro e assim por diante. Estou precisando dar um espaço entre os meses para que visualmente fique melhor o entendimento. Alguém já utilizou esses tipo de gráfico?

Comment: Bom dia Carlos, eu nunca utilizei esse Frame. mas já utilizei o Chart.js, de uma olhada, também é bem fácil e simples de mexer.

Comment: Conheço o Chart, o problema que esse q preciso arrumar ja esta sendo usado no sistema, e para mudar vai ser muito complicado. Mas obrigado.

Comment: apresente o seu código e esclareça melhor o seu problema/intenção;

Comment: Consegui achar uma saida, nao foi o ideal mas atendeu a necessidade. Muito obrigado a todos